# Bibliography - restrict the number of authors

Tags: bibliographies

How to restrict the number of authors to be viewed in document? Or is it all right to write it in this way?

```
@article{Pablo2016,
  author={H. Pablo and G. N. Whittaker and A. Popowicz and S. M. Mochnacki and R. Kuschnig and C. C. Grant and A. F. J. Moffat and S. M.
Rucinski and J. M. Matthews and A. Schwarzenberg-Czerny and G. Handler and W. W. Weiss and D. Baade and G. A. Wade and E.
Zocłońska and T. Ramiaramanantsoa and M. Unterberger and K. Zwintz and A. Pigulski and J. Rowe and O. Koudelka and P.
Orleański and A. Pamyatnykh and C. Neiner and R. Wawrzaszek and G. Marciniszyn and P. Romano and G. Woźniak and T.
```

[image]

```
\bibliographystyle{czplainnat}    

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Seznam použité literatury}

\bibliography{literatura}
```

I cite

```
\citet{}
```

or

```
\citep{}
```

Comment: use maxnames or maxbibnames, see the biblatex documentation.

Comment: Whether or not the full author list is required or not depends on the particular journal/scientific society style, and is not really a TeX question. Some styles (e.g. APA) require `\dots` between the 7th and last authors.  Ulrike's comment shows you how to control the numbers in the more simple cases if needed.  Some

Comment: Note that Ulrike's suggestion only works if you are really using `biblatex` (as your tagging suggests). If you are not using `biblatex` a different method may be needed. Please show us not only your `.bib` entry but also a short example document that demonstrates which bibliography and citation packages you load (e.g. `cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...), which style you use (the argument of `\bibliographystyle` for BibTeX-based solution or the value of the `style` option for `biblatex`) and how you create your bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. The code you have shown us so far is not a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), which is what I gad in mind when I asked for an example document. *Please* consider adding useful code examples to your questions in the future. You have already quite some experience on this site and in almost all of your question an MWE was either integral in helping your or made things much easier. It gets a bit frustrating (and is ineffective) if we have to ask for more information every time before we can start helping you.

Comment: Anyway, the code shown so far shows that the question was tagged incorrectly (so I retagged it). That means that Ulrike's advice won't work for you. `czplainnat` has no built-in option to restrict the number of displayed names as easily as `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `biblatex` and the program `biber`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{Pablo2016,
    author={H. Pablo and G. N. Whittaker and A. Popowicz and S. M. Mochnacki and R. Kuschnig 
        and C. 
            C. Grant and A. F. J. Moffat and S. M.
            Rucinski and J. M. Matthews and A. Schwarzenberg-Czerny and G. Handler and W. W. Weiss 
            and 
            D. Baade and G. A. Wade and E.
            Zocłońska and T. Ramiaramanantsoa and M. Unterberger and K. Zwintz and A. Pigulski and 
            J. 
            Rowe and O. Koudelka and P.
            Orleański and A. Pamyatnykh and C. Neiner and R. Wawrzaszek and G. Marciniszyn and P. 
            Romano and G. Woźniak and T.},
        title ={An article with a lot of authors},
        date ={2018-12-20},
        journal= {The journal for Articles},
        location ={New York and Bangkok},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

foo~\parencite{Pablo2016} or bar~\textcite{Pablo2016}

\printbibliography[title=Seznam použité literatury]

\makeatletter  % only for demonstration
\def\blx@maxbibnames{1}
\blx@resetdata
\makeatother

\printbibliography[title=Seznam použité literatury]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `biblatex` instead of BibTeX and `bibliographysytle`. is not really difficult: Replace your

```
\bibliographystyle{czplainnat}    
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Seznam použité literatury}
\bibliography{literatura}
```

with the following which should go into the preamble(!):

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<your bibfile>.bib}
```

in the text use `\textcite`, \parencite`, or simply`\cite` and at the end

```
\printbibliography[title=Seznam použité literatury]
```

Comment: Thank you very much and is it possible to write this to .bib file?

Comment: With `\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=1]{biblatex}` you already get the last one.

Comment: What should I replace? I get error ! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \newlength{\bibhang}

Comment: see edited answer at the end, where I wrote what you should do. I suppose that you already have natbib or something else loaded.

Comment: I have `\usepackage{natbib}         
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`

Comment: `natbib` is no more needed for `biblatex`

Comment: Thank you and what does this error mean? ! Package biblatex Error: File 'prace.bbl' not created by biblatex.See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{document}

Comment: that it is an old bbl-file, created by bibtex and not biber. Delete it and run the document again.

Comment: Where should I deleted it?

Comment: in the folder of your document. Some Editors have an option like "Clear all help files". Then it is done by the editor.

Comment: I don't have such editor. What suffix have these files?

Comment: Your document has the filename `prace.tex` and you know the directory in which you saved this document. And in this directory are all the other help files, like `prace.log`, `prace.aux`... , and `brace.bbl`. This one you should delete.

Comment: I have used `\citet` and `\citep` up to now. Is `\textcite`, `\parencite` and `\cite` excatly tha same?

Comment: Or is it possible in .bib file deleted some authors and write etal. manually?

Comment: yes, they are the same and it makes no sense to it manually.